# Unable to import tensor flow and keras properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have wrote this code in python here. I have a dataset in json and i am trying to train that dataset using keras. I was able to load data perfectly but after writing the complete code to train my dataset and running it, it started giving me errors in imports of my program. I tried installing tensorflowjs and keras using pip again but everytime i try tensorflowjs it start giving me compatibilty error on kerasApplications version. I tried installing every version but it is still giving me the same error. How can i get out of this trouble?

```
import json
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
with open("C:\\Users\\TechProBox\\Desktop\\Model.json") as f:
data = json.load(f)
x1 = np.array(data['attiude.roll'])
y1 = np.array(data['attitude.pitch'])
z1 = np.array(data['attitude.yaw'])
x2 = np.array(data['gravity.x'])
y2 = np.array(data['gravity.y'])
z2 = np.array(data['gravity.z'])
x3 = np.array(data['rotationRate.x'])
y3 = np.array(data['rotationRate.y'])
z3 = np.array(data['rotationRate.z'])
x4 = np.array(data['userAcceleration.x'])
y4 = np.array(data['userAcceleration.y'])
z4 = np.array(data['userAcceleration.z'])

x1_train = x1[:-10000]
y1_train = y1[:-10000]
z1_train = z1[:-10000]
x2_train = x2[:-10000]
y2_train = y2[:-10000]
z2_train = z2[:-10000]
x3_train = x3[:-10000]
y3_train = y3[:-10000]
z3_train = z3[:-10000]
x4_train = x4[:-10000]
y4_train = y4[:-10000]
z4_train = z4[:-10000]
x1_test = x1[:-10000]
y1_test = y1[:-10000]
z1_test = z1[:-10000]
x2_test = x2[:-10000]
y2_test = y2[:-10000]
z2_test = z2[:-10000]
x3_test = x3[:-10000]
y3_test = y3[:-10000]
z3_test = z3[:-10000]
x4_test = x4[:-10000]
y4_test = y4[:-10000]
z4_test = z4[:-10000]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=6))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x1_train, y1_train, z1_train, x2_train, y2_train, z2_train,x3_train, y3_train, z3_train,
            x4_train, y4_train, z4_train,
            epochs=14,
            batch_size=128)

score = model.evaluate(x1_test, y2_test, z3_test, x2_test, y2_test, z2_test, x3_test, y3_test, z3_test,
                        x4_test, y4_test, z4_test, batch_size=128)

print(score)
model.save("Keras-64*2-10epoch")
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model,"tfjsv3")
```

Here are the errors

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TechProBox\Desktop\Python1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: from kera.models import Sequential, you forgot 's' of the keras on the 4th line

Comment: @gunes yup but still facing same error

Comment: Check here: maybe relevant https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046

Comment: @IcedLance yes this was a protobuff issue and i just needed to install protobuff and it worked :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to isntall protobuff and it worked

```
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```